# Reading point cloud data out of a postgresql pgPointcloud database using PDAL

Tags: c++, docker, postgis, pdal, pgpointcloud

I want to read point cloud data from a postgres database.

Here is my code

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

ENV TZ=UTC
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=nointeractive

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip wget
RUN apt-get install libpcl-dev cmake libgtest-dev -y 
RUN apt-get install build-essential

RUN pip config set global.trusted-host "pypi.org files.pythonhosted.org pypi.python.org"

RUN wget -P /tmp https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py310_23.1.0-1-Linux-x86_64.sh --no-check-certificate
RUN bash /tmp/Miniconda3-py310_23.1.0-1-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p /home/spacesium/miniconda
ENV PATH="/home/spacesium/miniconda/bin:$PATH"

RUN conda config --set ssl_verify false
RUN conda install -c conda-forge pdal python-pdal gdal

WORKDIR /app
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
services:

  edge:
    build: .
    command: sh -c "pdal pipeline /app/pipeline.json"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

pipeline.json

```json
[
    {
        "type":"readers.pgpointcloud",
        "connection":"dbname='dbname' user='username' password='password' host='localhost' port=5432",
        "table":"patches",
        "column":"pa",
        "where":"id=1"
    },
    {
        "type":"writers.text",
        "filename":"outputfile.txt"
    }
]
```

When I run it all using `docker compose up`

I get the error message

```
 PDAL: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
   Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
 connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Cannot assign requested address
   Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

Interestingly, when I run the pdal command on my local development PC (ie: not within a docker container) from a conda environment the command works fine.

ie: `pdal pipeline pipeline.json`

[image: data]

---

**UPDATE:**

Building the current container and tagging it
`docker build . -t das-edge:latest`

I then added this to the docker compose script which hosts the database:

```yaml
edge:
    image: das-edge:latest
    command: sh -c "pdal pipeline /app/pipeline.json"
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - "db:hdasdb"
    networks:
      - "app-network"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

I get this error message:

```
2023-12-11 03:53:15.148 UTC [33] LOG:  Pointcloud (1.2.5) module loaded
2023-12-11 03:53:15.148 UTC [33] STATEMENT:  SELECT PC_Typmod_Pcid(a.atttypmod) AS pcid FROM pg_class c, pg_attribute a WHERE c.relname = 'patches' AND a.attname = 'pa' AND a.attrelid = c.oid
(pdal pipeline readers.pgpointcloud Error) GDAL failure (1) PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Open of /home/spacesium/miniconda/share/proj failed
PDAL: Could not import coordinate system 'EPSG:32756': PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Open of /home/spacesium/miniconda/share/proj failed.
```

Which seems to relate to this:
[Error Message Source Code](https://github.com/PDAL/PDAL/blob/7d3ec480e04ef0d7f821a3be67fb4165bfbf896b/pdal/SpatialReference.cpp#L245)

It's strange that I get this error message only when inside a docker container.

Comment: Any feedback on how to improve this question is also welcome

Comment: Where is the database actually running?  It looks like you've configured the container to try to connect to `localhost`, but in Docker that almost always refers to the current container only.

Comment: @DavidMaze I have another docker container with the database on it.

Comment: @DavidMaze I tried getting the ip address of the container using 
`docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' das-api-db-1`
but this does not appear to give the right address as I still get a connection error

Comment: Is this really a C++ question? Where is the problematic code? Why do you post a text in the picture whereas you have successfully inserted other text above the picture?

Comment: @273K I'm not really sure if this is a C++ question, perhaps it depends on what the solution is. I've tried using a c++ program that uses pdal/PipelineManager.hpp to create the pipeline to connect to the database and I get the same error.

Comment: https://github.com/PDAL/PDAL/blob/7d3ec480e04ef0d7f821a3be67fb4165bfbf896b/scripts/docker/ubuntu/Dockerfile

Comment: That `docker inspect` IP address is essentially useless.  You don't need it for connections between containers, since Docker networks provide an internal DNS system.   From outside a container, it's unreachable except in one extremely specific configuration, and connecting to a `docker run -p` published port is more portable and better practice.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include details of how you're launching the database container?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to DavidMaze for pointing me to the first problem

The error message mentions `proj_create_from_database`, which is mentioned in a number of [tickets](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3APDAL%2FPDAL%20proj_create_from_database&type=issues) in the PDAL library.

Reading through these issues, it would seem to suggest that the PDAL library may still not be installed correctly in the docker container.

I have used the following docker file:

```
FROM condaforge/mambaforge:latest as build

ENV LANG=C.UTF-8 LC_ALL=C.UTF-8

RUN conda config --set ssl_verify false
RUN pip config set global.trusted-host "pypi.org files.pythonhosted.org pypi.python.org"

RUN conda create -n pdal -y
ARG GITHUB_SHA
ARG GITHUB_REPOSITORY="PDAL/PDAL"
ARG GITHUB_SERVER_URL="https://github.com"

SHELL ["conda", "run", "-n", "pdal", "/bin/bash", "-c"]

RUN git config --global http.sslVerify false

RUN mamba install -c conda-forge git compilers conda-pack cmake make ninja sysroot_linux-64=2.17 && \
    mamba install --yes -c conda-forge pdal --only-deps

RUN git clone "${GITHUB_SERVER_URL}/${GITHUB_REPOSITORY}" pdal && \
    cd pdal ; \
    git checkout ${GITHUB_SHA}

RUN mkdir -p pdal/build && \
    cd pdal/build  && \
    CXXFLAGS="-Werror=strict-aliasing" LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath-link,$CONDA_PREFIX/lib" cmake -G Ninja  \
        -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
        -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH:FILEPATH="$CONDA_PREFIX/lib" \
        -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH:FILEPATH="$CONDA_PREFIX/include" \
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="$CONDA_PREFIX" \
        -DBUILD_PLUGIN_CPD=OFF \
        -DBUILD_PLUGIN_PGPOINTCLOUD=ON \
        -DBUILD_PLUGIN_NITF=ON \
        -DBUILD_PLUGIN_ICEBRIDGE=ON \
        -DBUILD_PLUGIN_HDF=ON \
        -DBUILD_PLUGIN_TILEDB=ON \
        -DBUILD_PLUGIN_E57=ON \
        -DBUILD_PGPOINTCLOUD_TESTS=OFF \
        -DWITH_ZSTD=ON \
        ..

RUN cd pdal/build  && \
    ninja

#RUN cd pdal/build  && \
#    ctest -V

RUN cd pdal/build  && \
    ninja install

RUN conda-pack -n pdal --dest-prefix=/opt/conda/envs/pdal -o  /tmp/env.tar && \
     mkdir /venv && cd /venv && tar xf /tmp/env.tar  && \
     rm /tmp/env.tar

FROM condaforge/miniforge3

ENV CONDAENV "/opt/conda/envs/pdal"
COPY --from=build /venv "/opt/conda/envs/pdal"

ENV PROJ_NETWORK=TRUE
ENV PROJ_DATA="${CONDAENV}/share/proj"
ENV GDAL_DATA="${CONDAENV}/share/gdal"
ENV GEOTIFF_CSV="${CONDAENV}/share/epsg_csv"
ENV GDAL_DRIVER_PATH="${CONDAENV}/lib/gdalplugins"
ENV PATH $PATH:${CONDAENV}/bin
ENV GTIFF_REPORT_COMPD_CS=TRUE
ENV REPORT_COMPD_CS=TRUE
ENV OAMS_TRADITIONAL_GIS_ORDER=TRUE


SHELL ["conda", "run", "--no-capture-output", "-n", "pdal", "/bin/sh", "-c"]
```

This was mostly from [PDAL Docker Script](https://github.com/PDAL/PDAL/blob/7d3ec480e04ef0d7f821a3be67fb4165bfbf896b/scripts/docker/ubuntu/Dockerfile)

Building and tagging this image:
`docker build . -t das-edge:latest`

Docker Compose:

```
  edge:
    image: das-edge:latest
    command: sh -c "pdal pipeline /app/pipeline.json"
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - "db:hdasdb"
    networks:
      - "app-network"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

pipeline.json

```json
[
    {
        "type":"readers.pgpointcloud",
        "connection":"dbname='dbname' user='username' password='password' host='localhost' port=5432",
        "table":"patches",
        "column":"pa",
        "where":"id=1"
    },
    {
        "type":"writers.text",
        "filename":"outputfile.txt"
    }
]
```